# How do I make my program have the decimal value and character that goes with it?

Tags: javascript, binary, character, ascii

I want to convert Binary to a Character using JavaScript. I already have a binary to decimal converter. Now I need a decimal to Char converter. What is the best way to make my program have the decimal value of each Char without using a ton of separate variables, or a ton of if statements to determine the char? I am only working with ASCII.

Note:
I am not running it in a web browser. I am just running it directly in VS Code if that makes a difference

Edit:
I have a bin to dec converter. Now I need to convert dec to char.

I'm not really sure what to try.

Comment: Why not just [`String.fromCodePoint(...yourArrayOfNumbers)`](//developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/fromCodePoint)?

Comment: "Now I need a decimal to Char converter." What exactly should this do?  Can you provide example(s)?